# Calibrating a k type themperature probe for a PID controller

Tags: calibration

I just purchased an inkbird PID controller with a k probe to controll a temperature in an oven. I calibrated the k probe at 60F using a trusted digital thermometer with 2 probes.

I installed the probe in the oven and increased the temperature to 120F (measured with the trusted thermometer). My PID was increasing the temperature a lot slower than my thermometer and never went above 100F. So, at 60F both are showing the same temp, but at 120F there is a big discrepancy.

I calibrated at 120F, and now both show close readings in the 120 range, but when decreasing and increasing the temperature, the discrepancy is increaing. The farter from 120, the higher the discrepancy.

So, the question is if I calibrate the k probe at a certain temperature, will the measurement be accurate only in a small range, close to that temperature? Thsi doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: 2nd paragraph observation: If the temperature never went above 100°F how can you make comparisons at 120°F?

Comment: We have no idea what procedure you followed for this "calibration". A "k probe" is most likely a K type thermocouple which, along with the correct thermocouple amplifier, should be accurate over a thousand degree range. Consult this inky bird to see if it supports this thermocouple properly.

Comment: Andy, what I meant is My PID was increasing the temp to 120 (measured with a thermometer) but my PID was showing only 100.

Comment: Brian, what I did and call callibration is : bring the temperature inside the oven at 60F for a long time, until the k probe temp stopped increasing. The PID using the k probe was showing 75F, so I compensated in the PID settings with a minus 15 , so now the PID is showing 60. But when I increase the temp to 120 in the oven, the  PID is showing only 100. Now, if I do the similar adjustment in the settings to plus 20, the PID will read 120 when the oven is at 120, but when lowering the temp, at 60 in the oven, the PID shows 80

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have exactly the same issue. I'd nearly suggest that the Inkbird Thermocouple is not actually K type the way it's behaving.